# how to install google chrome extensions with settings by script

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I try to install as much as possible script based
to ensure uniformity and low maintenance effort.

I use suse linux and to install applications as e.g. Google Chrome
I use a script invoking `zypper`.
The next step is to install the needed extensions to Google Chrome also by script.
Many extensions require configuration also.
So ideal would be to install the extensions together with the settings.
Is there a way to do so?